# Property of Bread Dough

Tags: baking, bread, dough

I've been looking at the dough that Cinnabon uses: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mtTIS6apXIc. How would one describe the property of their dough? It almost looks like Play Doh, as if it were some sort of rubbery-like material.

Is this property called "elasticity?" If so, what factors affect the elasticity of a dough? If I wanted dough that had similar properties to Cinnabon's, what would I need to look out for in my recipe?

Comment: You could look up a recipe for cinnamon rolls. Most likely their dough uses a solid fat, milk and eggs. It's unlikely to be much different from the standard brioche type dough, only using cheaper ingredients.

Answer (score 3):

The video doesn't really show much of the dough or how it is handled, I only see a prepared square sheet being filled. But if you actually want dough which handles like play-dough, then the property is called not elasticity, but opposite, plasticity - it is a material which can be formed without springing back.

If that is what you want, for a bread dough, you can achieve it by 
- reducing the hydration 
- adding more butter 
- using a flour with little gluten content 
- not using any prolonged rises or techniques like stretch and fold, just doing a short rise, without getting it to go too voluminous

But bread dough is not really a good candidate for that, because it is usually elastic by nature. If you have a need for plastic dough, the best option would be to make a pasta dough with eggs and AP flour. It is plastic like no other. Or also salt dough for ornaments, it is not only a better play doh substitute, and keeps its shape after baking.

Comment: Pasta dough to make cinnamon rolls? Great insights by the way. I'm reading up on the points you raised.

Comment: Ah no, I didn't mean to suggest pasta dough for cinnamon rolls. I assumed that you want the dough for some other purpose, since the plasticity is not really something a baker would want to optimize for.

Comment: Sorry  for the confusion. Doesn't it look like Cinnabon optimizes for plasticity? Their dough looks like Play-doh. Very interesting to watch them roll it.

Comment: I doubt that they optimize for plasticity. Whatever they optimize for (probably low cost and high reproducibility), the plasticity is most likely an irrelevant side effect.